# using settings.xml file or a singleton class

Tags: c#, singleton

I have a windows service in which multiple tables are checked per request. The average load of requests is 100 requests per minute. I am using the project setting.xml file to store the connection strings.

Does it really matter if I use a singleton class or use the XML file? Is any mechanism used in reading the setting file to minimize access to this file? Should I use a singleton class and read the XML file in there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely shave a few milliseconds by using a singleton class, since it's in memory rather then on disk (as the settings file would be). Not a massive amount admittedly, but it's better then nothing.

Comment: You mean I write a singleton in which the constructor loads the settings file. right?

Comment: Yes you're right. Create an instance of the singleton and in it's constructor do a one time loading of the application settings. That way all the settings are in memory and there's no need to keep accessing an external settings file.